# What pickled yellow-green vegetable is this, in Chiu Chow Garden's appetizer?

Tags: chinese-cuisine

From top to bottom: [Top 1](https://stenoodie.com/2015/05/27/chiu-chow-garden-%e6%bd%ae%e5%ba%ad-hong-kong/). [2](http://www.jinlovestoeat.com/2013/08/chiuchow-garden.html).

> I loved this appetizer of tofu cubes, peanuts, pickled radish and beans

[3](https://www.tripadvisor.com/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g294217-d8004304-i231222310-Chiuchow_Garden_Restaurant_Infinitus_Plaza-Hong_Kong.html). [4](https://www.openrice.com/en/hongkong/p-chiuchow-garden-restaurant-p6850101). [5](https://www.openrice.com/en/hongkong/p-chiuchow-garden-restaurant-p5266276).

Is the  yellow-green vegetable  truly radish? What kind of radish? These pictures were taken at Chiu Chow Garden restaurant in Hong Kong that serves this appetizer.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that is [daikon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daikon), which has [many names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daikon#Names) including several that include the word "radish".

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of vegetables in there that are yellow-green, one is a leafy vegetable, which is likely some variant of [Chinese cabbage/Wong-Bok/Napa cabbage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napa_cabbage). This part will have the classic ribbed stems and pale leafy parts seen with these vegetables. This is the same cabbage used in many [Kimchi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kimchi) recipes, though these can also contain a bunch of other vegetables too.

The larger cube shaped pieces are likely to be, as @LSchoon noted, Daikon (lo-pak/lobak in Cantonese or Luobo in Mandarin). If this is the case, they will have (if you can piece together a ring made out of them) an outer layer that is less transparent than the middle, and radial rays that seem to emanate from the center of the daikon - you can see them in the picture associated with [this recipe](http://www.otakufood.com/easy-pickled-daikon-takuan/).